# AttributeError While Creating a Function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to create a function that reads my file and the column I want it to read:

```
def read_row(file, column):
   main_df = np.array([])
   for df in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize = 100000):
     column_name = df.column.unique()
     main_df = np.append(main_df,column_name)
return(main_df)
```

However it shows `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'`.
What should I put instead of column in `df.column.unique()`?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your variables are trying to achieve. Is column a string or an integer? If column was an integer and you're actually tring to get the column name it would be column_name = df.columns[column]. If that's not the case, you should consider adjusting your variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use brackets `[]` instead dot notation:

```
column_name = df[column].unique()
```